# spacing for nav bar margins aren't working react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, react-router

I followed along with this tutorial on building a react app: React JS Tutorial for Beginners #1 – Build a website using React, Sass, Gulp and Node.js

Everything works great except the spacing of the nav bar. The way he adjusts the spacing is in the:

Code: https://gist.github.com/kentonraiford/42cad2361cb6e47c7fd6b995013d50f4

I rewatched the video a few times and was unable to figure out where I messed up. This might be a simple fix but I can't seem to find the solution.

Link to file: https://github.com/kentonraiford/reactTutorial

Comment: pls provide the url from where r u learning

Comment: @amitwadhwani - the video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nusgoj74a3Y

Comment: thaks for that.

Answer (score 0):

In the repository that you posted, the problem is the css selector you're trying to use to apply the margin-right has less precedence so is margin-right property is being overwrite

```
header {
   nav ul li {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
}
```

> Precendence is calculate in this way
>
> **Element, Pseudo Element:** d = 1 – (0,0,0,1) 
>   **Class, Pseudo class, Attribute:** c = 1 – (0,0,1,0) 
>   **Id:** b = 1 – (0,1,0,0) 
>   **Inline Style:** a = 1 – (1,0,0,0)

So this selector will have this precedence: **(0, 0, 0, 4)**

```
header {
  ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

And the selector you use to add margin-right has **(0, 0, 0, 3)**

So the other selector has more Precedence that the selector that you want to use to apply margin-right to the li element

You can fix this problem by creating a more specific selector (adding a class or id to the selector) that is going to give it more precedence to overwrite other selectors or use !important (Not recommended way)

For example:

```
header {
  ul.header-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

Precedence: **(0, 0, 1, 3)**

More info about precedence:

http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/